# How does a tool like SEOMoz Rank Checker work?

Tags: web-services, google-api

It seems there are a number of tools that allow you to check a site's position in search results for long lists of keywords. I'd like to integrate a feature like that in an analytics project I'm working on, but I cannot think of a way to run queries at such high volumes (1000s per hour) without violating the Google TOS and potentially running afoul of their automatic query detection system (the one that institutes a CAPTCHA if search volume at your IP gets too high).

Is there an alternative method for running these automated searches, or is the only way forward to scrape search result pages?

Comment: So I figured out how to read the code, and it just scrapes the Google search result pages. I think running the queries from Firefox as a plugin helps mask the intent a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Use a third party to scrape it if you're scared of Google's TOS.

Answer (score 0):

Google is very hot on banning/blocking temporarily IP addresses that appear to be sending automated queries. And yes of course, this is against their TOS.

It's also quite difficult to know exactly how they are detecting them but the main reason is definitely identical keyword searches from the same IP address.

The short answer is basically: **Get a lot of proxies**

Some more tips:

- Don't search further than you need to (e.g. the first 10 pages)
- Wait around 4-5 seconds between queries for the same keyword
- Make sure you use real browser headers and not something like "CURL..."
- Stop scraping with an IP when you hit the road blocks and wait a few days before using the same proxy.
- Try and make your program act like a real user would and you won't have too many issues.

You can scrape Google quite easily but to do it at a very high volume will be challenging.